npm install doesn't install node modules
When I run the npm install command the package-lock.json file is created but the node modules folder is not created or the node modules are not installed.
When I run the npm install command getting the below error:
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/santosh/newdir/AWS-Session/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/santosh/newdir/AWS-Session/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/santosh/.npm/_logs/2024-08-29T05_37_59_133Z-debug-0.log

I have tried re-installing node but still no luck, getting the same error

It clearly says that you don't have package.json in the folder /home/santosh/newdir/AWS-Session/. Make sure you are in the correct location.

If package.json is missing and you need to create a new one, you can initialize a new package.json file

npm init -y



i have created the package.json file using "npm init -y" command but when i start the npm using "npm run start" then it throws me the below error saying node module is not installed.

santosh@LAPTOP-JOAPP58D:~/newdir/AWS-Session$ npm run start

aws-session@1.0.0 start
node server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:

/home/santosh/newdir/AWS-Session/server.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:85:18)


at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:85:18)
at Object. (/home/santosh/newdir/AWS-Session/server.js:1:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

requireStack: [ '/home/santosh/newdir/AWS-Session/server.js' ]
}
